# Merge .mp3 Files into one file .mp3 Android

Tags: android, merge, mp3

i have generate many .mp3 files and i need to merge it into on e mp3 file , i try this code :

```
FileInputStream fist = null;
    try {
        fist = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Flash Library/Resources/sound1.mp3");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
     FileInputStream fist2 = null;
    try {
        fist2 = new FileInputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Flash Library/Resources/sound2.mp3");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        File dir = new File ("/mnt/sdcard/Flash Library/dir1");
        dir.mkdirs();

        SequenceInputStream sistream = new SequenceInputStream(fist, fist2);

        FileOutputStream fostream = null;
        try {
            fostream = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/Flash Library/dir1/output.mp3");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        int temp;
        try {
            while( ( temp = sistream.read() ) != -1)
            {
                Toast.makeText(ctx.getActivity(), sistream.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // System.out.print( (char) temp ); // to print at DOS prompt
                fostream.write(temp);   // to write to file
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fostream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            sistream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fist.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fist2.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
```

firstly , it will generate file (output.mp3) have the only first mp3 data , the second will not add to output , Secondly i need to merge many mp3 files not just Two ?
i search for merging mp3 files and all recommended in Example above .
Is there any solution for my problem ?

Comment: What is your problem @Sameer H. Ibra  ?

Comment: @GrIsHu : I need a library that combine many .mp3 files into one file ?

Comment: i have same problem if you found solution please inform me

Answer (score 0):

It seems merging .mp3 files by adding one's content to the other's end works (as your code revealed too). Then it should be pretty easy to write one: (untested)

```
public void mergeMp3Files(File[] inputs, File output) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(output);
        for (File input : inputs) {
            FileInputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                IOUtils.copy(inputStream = new FileInputStream(input),
                             outputStream);
            } finally {
                if (inputStream != null) try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (outputStream != null) try {
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't have an `IOUtils.copy`, here's one for you:

```
public class IOUtils {
    private static final int BUF_SIZE = 0x1000; // 4K

    public static long copy(InputStream from, OutputStream to)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buf = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
        long total = 0;
        while (true) {
            int r = from.read(buf);
            if (r == -1) {
                break;
            }
            to.write(buf, 0, r);
            total += r;
        }
        return total;
    }
}
```